# Misalignment when displaying image on different browsers

Tags: html

This is quick simple but I'm really a noob and don't know how to resolve this.

Basically, I have an e-card to be displayed on a webpage. There's an image and music playing in the background. The html works fine on Chrome and Firefox (centralised and playing well even though size differs on Chrome and Firefox) but the main problem lies on IE. When I open the webpage on IE, the image is not aligned correctly.

Below is my html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 background-color: #214353;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div align="center"><img src="image/Christmas-Card3.gif" width="800" height="533" /></div>
<div>
  <div align="center">
    <embed src="media/Feliz Navidad Instrumental Karaoke..mp3" width="32" height="32" hidden="ture" loop="ture"></embed>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use this style on your container div.

```
<div style="width: 800px; height: 533px; margin: 0 auto;"><img src="image/Christmas-Card3.gif" width="800" height="533" /></div>
```